# Opening WebView link with control panel

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a WebView with control panel like on image. And I need to not
take the user out of the application. So if person tap on "cross", he will back to the application. How do I do that?

[image]

```
class WebViewVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var url: String
    
    init(url: String) {
        self.url = url
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
   }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let url = URL(string: self.url) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
            webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        }
    }
}
```